# Running ASP.NET Core within/alongside an existing ASP.NET WebForms project in Visual Studio and IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, iis-express

I have a large Visual Studio solution with several ASP.NET web sites with a mix of WebForms, MVC and WebAPI. What I'd like to be able to do is add an ASP.NET Core project to this solution to provide MVC, Razor Pages, WebAPI and SPA (Vue.JS in this case) facilities. The plan is to take each WebForms page at a time and convert to the new framework.

I'll target .NET Framework and the Core site will share some assemblies from the WebForms - but no state is shared except a session cookie and any state stored in the database.

I specifically want to be able to serve the new framework from IIS Express on the same port. So for example, an old page such as http://localhost:1234/page1.aspx will be converted to http://localhost:1234/core/page1. However, I'm unable to simply change the Core project to be hosted on IIS Express and change the path to http://localhost:1234/core. I have managed by [following instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2) to host in IIS but this has several disadvantages for development. I've also tried adding `<urlRewrite>` configuration to the WebForms site to forward requests to Core running on a different port but I wasn't very successful and I believe POST request are not supported which renders it fairly useless!

Comment: POST requests are supported